# How does transition rate behave under $T \rightarrow \infty$ limit

Tags: quantum-mechanics, integration, perturbation-theory, dirac-delta-distributions, fermis-golden-rule

I am supposed to learn Fermi's Golden Rule, and the book I am using for that is *Modern Particle Physics* by Mark Thomson. On page 52, he goes :

> The transition rate $d\Gamma_{fi} = \frac{1}{T}|{T_{fi}^2}| \int_{-\frac{T}{2}}^{\frac{T}{2}}\int_{-\frac{T}{2}}^{\frac{T}{2}} e^{i(E_f-E_i)t} e^{-i(E_f-E_i)t'}dtdt'$

which you integrate give a term of form upto scalar $\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}$.

Indeed exact calculation yields:
$$d\Gamma_{fi} = \frac{4|T_{fi}|^2}{T(\Delta E)^2}\sin^2{\frac{\Delta ET}{2}}$$

where $\Delta E := E_f - E_i$

Now, what I don't understand is, author discusses that this function is locally around $\frac{\Delta ET}{2} = 0$ has spikes and rapidly goes close to zero and then says 'narrowness of the functional form means that for all practical purposes, it can be written as

$$d\Gamma_{fi} = |{T_{fi}^2}| \lim_{T\rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{1}{T}\int_{-\frac{T}{2}}^{\frac{T}{2}}\int_{-\frac{T}{2}}^{\frac{T}{2}} e^{i(E_f-E_i)t} e^{-i(E_f-E_i)t'}dtdt'\right) $$

Now, what I didn't understand is how did we take the limit? What is (if there is) the usual way of assigning it a value? Or, since we are going to integrate $d\Gamma_{fi}$ all unnecessary terms will sort of "cancel itself"?